# How do I parse a non-standard commandline argument with clap? -bypas1234567890

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments, clap

I have a rust application that uses clap to parse its arguments, but I need to be able to accept an argument that changes every time it is called.  The argument will always start with the same 6 characters -bypas, but the next 10 characters will change with every call.  Is there a way with clap to partially identify an argument?

Comment: Sounds like the next 10 characters are an argument to the option, and not part of the option itself?

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes, that is exactly what it is.  It is an option and argument that are smashed together and will be passed to me if I am called by any of our legacy apps.  I am new to rust, so I was hoping that there was some trick I don't know, but I suspect that I am just going to have to grab a copy of the arguments, outside of clap, and search for this one argument myself.